# MySQL PHP Query in CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need help with this. I must pass a PHP MySQL function to CodeIgniter, but it does not show me the data, it stops right in **if(array_key_exists($pos, $rs))**

Does the query well but does not enter the conditional if

Any solution?

**This is my Code in CodeIgniter**

```
public function table($hour, $row)
    {
        global $rs;
        if ($rs === null) 
        {
          $this->db->select("CONCAT(t.tbl_row, '_', t.tbl_col) as pos, t.tbl_id, t.sub_id, s.sub_name", false);
          $this->db->join('redips_timetable AS t', 't.sub_id = s.sub_id');
          $rs = $this->db->get('redips_subject AS s')->result(); 
        }
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="mark dark">' . $hour . '</td>';
        for ($col = 1; $col <= 5; $col++) 
        {
          echo '<td>';
          $pos = $row . '_' . $col;
          if(array_key_exists($pos, $rs)) 
          {
            $elements = $rs[$pos];
            $id = $elements['sub_id'] . 'b' . $elements['tbl_id'];
            $name = $elements['sub_name'];
            $class = substr($id, 0, 2); 
            echo "<div id=\"$id\" class=\"redips-drag $class\">$name</div>";
          }
          echo '</td>';
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
      }
```

**Original MySQL code**

```
function table($hour, $row) {
    global $rs;
    // if $rs is null then query database (this should be executed only once - first time)
    if ($rs === null) 
    {
        // first column of the query is used as key in returned array
        $rs = sqlQuery("select concat(t.tbl_row,'_',t.tbl_col) as pos, t.tbl_id, t.sub_id, s.sub_name
                        from redips_timetable t, redips_subject s
                        where t.sub_id = s.sub_id", 0);
    }
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td class="mark dark">' . $hour . '</td>';
    // column loop starts from 1 because column 0 is for hours
    for ($col = 1; $col <= 5; $col++) {
        // create table cell
        print '<td>';
        // prepare position key in the same way as the array key looks
        $pos = $row . '_' . $col;
        // if content for the current table cell exists
        if (array_key_exists($pos, $rs)) {
            // prepare elements for defined position (it can be more than one element per table cell)
            $elements = $rs[$pos];
            // id of DIV element will start with sub_id and followed with 'b' (because cloned elements on the page have 'c') and with tbl_id
            // this way content from the database will not be in collision with new content dragged from the left table and each id stays unique
            $id = $elements[2] . 'b' . $elements[1];
            $name = $elements[3];
            $class = substr($id, 0, 2); // class name is only first 2 letters from ID
            print "<div id=\"$id\" class=\"redips-drag $class\">$name</div>";

        }
        // close table cell
        print '</td>';
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: I guess first thing to check is what `$rs` contains

Comment: Usage of globals in codeigniter? What troubleshooting steps have you taken? What are your input values?

Answer (score 0):

/*
if you need find array key

you got object in $rs varible 
( $rs = $this->db->get('redips_subject AS s')->result(); )
so need convert obj to array in for each loop
*/

```
public function table($hour, $row)
{
    global $rs;
    if ($rs === null) 
    {
      $this->db->select("CONCAT(t.tbl_row, '_', t.tbl_col) as pos, t.tbl_id, t.sub_id, s.sub_name", false);
      $this->db->join('redips_timetable AS t', 't.sub_id = s.sub_id');
      $rs = $this->db->get('redips_subject AS s')->result(); 
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="mark dark">' . $hour . '</td>';
    for ($col = 1; $col <= 5; $col++) 
    {
    $arr = get_object_vars($rs[$col]);
      echo '<td>';
      $pos = $row . '_' . $col;
      if(array_key_exists($pos, $arr))
      {
        $elements = $arr[$pos];
        $id = $elements['sub_id'] . 'b' . $elements['tbl_id'];
        $name = $elements['sub_name'];
        $class = substr($id, 0, 2); 
        echo "<div id=\"$id\" class=\"redips-drag $class\">$name</div>";
      }
      echo '</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
```